# Multiple sources to turn on furnace fan

Tags: heating

I am using multiple heat sources and would like to monitor the furnace duct and turn on the furnace fan if it becomes warm and the fan is not on.  Since the thermostat or Fan Limit Control and the duct monitor will both energize the green wire, is there any chance of damaging the thermostat, Fan Limit Control or Fan Relay?  (actually not sure the Fan Limit Control uses the green wire.)  The monitor could provide the R voltage to the Green wire while the thermostat or Fan Limit Control is off and one could come on while the other is on.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. It's hard to understand your situation; would you add a picture or diagram (or two) to your question, so we can better help you?

Comment: Can you post the wiring diagram for your air handler?